# Strange linker error while compiling OpenCV2.3.1 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: opencv, compilation, linker, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile OpenCV version 2.3.1 on an Ubuntu 11.10 following instructions described [here](http://ozbots.org/opencv-installation/). I'm getting following error. Can't understand what is happening... `/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a` exists but linker can't link against it, or something else?

error:

```
[ 20%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_highgui
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(avpacket.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `av_destruct_packet' 
can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling with -fPIC as the error suggests?

Comment: Compile what ? OpenCV itself?

Comment: @RCE How do I add -fPIC flag to compiler/linker ? Should I edit MakeFile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to link `libopencv_highgui.so` with `libavcodec.a`. The latter is built from code compiled without `-fPIC` (which is quite usual), and such code can not be linked into shared libraries on `x86_64`.

Your choices are:

- Obtain `libavcodec.so` and arrange to link against it, or
- Remove `libavcodec` or `-lavcodec` from the link line completely.

For the first, you most likely just need to install [libavcodec-dev](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libavcodec-dev) package.

If you do the second, you will still have to arrange for symbols that `libopencv_highgui.so` needs from `libavcodec` to be available at runtime. You can achieve that by linking the main executable with `libavcodec` (either archive or shared variant).

Comment: I add --enable-pic option to both x264 and ffmpeg. Got the same error. Then removed libhighgui and libcv (installed from ubuntu repositories) and also installed libavc-1394-22-dev. Compiled OpenCV again and it's working fine! Thanks

Comment: How did you remove libhighgui and libcv ? Can you also send a link to libavc-1394-22-dev

Answer (score 4):

my take would be that, first run sudo apt-get remove libavcodec , then re-install with sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev

I once had similar issue, and the above resolved it

Answer (score 2):

Running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu you have to configure and build ffmpeg with
`./configure --enable-shared --enable-pic`
as it is described in step 7b and 8b