# Error installing OpenCV 2.3.1 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: opencv

Here is the error that I get:

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(avpacket.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `av_destruct_packet' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Has anybody encountered an error like this? How do I work around it?

Comment: follow the approach as suggested by kleinash or see [this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370028/strange-linker-error-while-compiling-opencv2-3-1-on-ubuntu-11-10/18059215#18059215

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with the FFMPEG. You need to recompile it with the --enable-shared option. That could probably do the deal for you.

Answer (score 1):

I installed OpenCV 2.3.1 on Ubuntu 11.10 couple days ago. All you have to do is to fallow the steps from http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/ Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using older version of ffmpeg. You should use ffmpeg 0.8+. [Here](http://opencvlover.blogspot.in/) is the guide for ubuntu 12.04 which works for 11.10 as well

Answer (score 1):

that is the same tutorial I followed - however it is no good with 12.04 because you end up overwriting a number of libraries and (in my newbie case) reinstall *everything* sudo apt-get came to the rescue - but again you have to look at how the libraries are linked and use: `$ g++ -o hello_world hello-world.cpp` `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` (use  back quote symbol) if you want anything to compile.

btw - best tutorial for opencv2 (installation and usage) ever: http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html