# Error while installing OpenCV

Tags: linux, opencv

I have used the following commands to install OpenCV 2.4.3 on my Linux Ubunbtu 12.04

```
cmake -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=OFF -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_BUILD_3RDPARTY_LIBS=ON -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_OPENEXR=ON -D WITH_OPENNI=ON -D WITH_PNG=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_XINE=ON -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON .
```

followed bythe make command.
During the make, I get the following error.

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(avpacket.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against     
`av_destruct_packet' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have updated linux. I am unable to figure out the error. Please help.

Comment: There seems to be a solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370028/strange-linker-error-while-compiling-opencv2-3-1-on-ubuntu-11-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bug in the libav build system, not OpenCV. Thus, to discard this, you can try to recompile with `-D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF`

Anyway this post is duplicated: [Strange linker error while compiling OpenCV2.3.1 on Ubuntu 11.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370028/strange-linker-error-while-compiling-opencv2-3-1-on-ubuntu-11-10)

Comment: Sorry I just edited the answer, try with '-D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF'